# The difference between size of datatype and sizeof(data type)

Tags: c++, c

I was learning C++ and come across the following question. I'm just a beginner and I got confused. Isn't sizeof() function supposed to return the size of the datatype? Why could a data object has different size from its sizeof()? I don't understand the explanation of the answer.

Suppose in a hypothetical machine, the size of char is 32 bits. What would sizeof(char) return?

a) 4

b) 1

c) Implementation dependent

d) Machine dependent

Answer:b

Explanation: The standard does NOT require a char to be 8-bits, but does require that sizeof(char) return 1.

Comment: I don't understand you question. What do you mean with "why could a data object has different size from its sizeof()?"?

Comment: @Superlokkus His example `char` is `4` bytes big but `sizeof(char)` returns `1`. And `4 != 1`.

Comment: @cad: No, a `char` is 1 byte by definition. On that system, a byte is 32 bits.

Comment: Sorry, I might have confused you. In the question it says that on a machine the size of char is 32bits, but the sizeof(char) is 1. I thought sizeof(char) will also be 32, isn't it? Isn't char a single character? It is because the machine deliberately assign 32 bits to a char type, but eventually the sizeof(char) only return the real size of it? In that case the other digits are simply wasted.

Comment: _@KennethChen_ You should have written your own answer, not answering in the question. Answering your own questions is perfectly OK and actually appreciated.

Comment: It won't be `32` even in that case. One could think it would be `4 = 32/8` in the worst case.

Comment: `sizeof` yields the size *in bytes*. If a `char` is 32 bits, then a byte is 32 bits. We don't know that any of the bits are wasted; a `char` can hold any of 2**32 distinct values.

Comment: "The standard does NOT require a char to be 8-bits, but does require that sizeof(char) return 1." You answerded your question already. What is your point?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, in the worst *and only* case, `sizeof (char) == 1`

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Why the `8`? It is actually `32`, because `CHAR_BIT` would be `32` here.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes you're right! I learned that a byte is 8 digits, I didn't know that byte could have a different number of bits! I got it now.

Comment: @KeithThompson Do you mind reading the whole comment?  Olaf: `sizeof` is never returning the bit size

Comment: @Olaf Yeah I just didn't understand the explanation.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The range is not necessarily realted. That's what  `CHAR_MAX` & friends are for.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I read the whole comment. What did I miss?

Comment: @Olaf, oh, I see. I mean one that thinks that the `sizeof` is returning the number of octets. Which is a plenty of people.

Comment: @KeithThompson Perhaps I wasn't clear, see my previous comment to Olaf.

Comment: @KennethChen: Your teachers were wrong. A type with 8 bits is an **octet**. The width of a byte is machine-dependent. It's just that most architectures **nowadays** have 8 bits/byte. Some decades ago e.g. 9 bits  were quite common. And on some DSPs it still has e.g. 24 bits.

Comment: @Olaf while you are formally right, people are mostly trying to refer the non-octet-sized bytes as "machine words"

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yeah, bad enough. Perhaps time for a new architecture with  11 bits (next larger prime would be nice). You have the phone number of Intel? ;-)

Comment: Add BTW: "*Isn't sizeof() function ...*" `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @alk: While you are right, I actually wish it was a function. Anyway, I confess, I always use parenthesis, although they are semantically not for `sizeof`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, a "machine word" is normally the size of the (data) registers. That would be e.g. 32 bits for ARM <v8 or x86. A byte is the smallest seperately addressable unit. That's the reason it's size may vary. The WP article is worth reading, although it also concentrates a bit too much on  "byte <=> 8 bits" imo. I also used to take this "shortcut". Since some years, I tend to prefer "octets" or define "byte == 8 bits" in my documenation.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Referring to bytes, even 32-bit bytes, as "words" is IMHO not helpful. A word may be several bytes wide. For example, a machine might have 16-bit bytes and 64-bit words. The standard doesn't even talk about "words".

Comment: @Olaf What's "WP article"?

Comment: @Olaf: One is never to old to learn. I had dropped this habit after about 20 years ... ;-)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Sorry, I'm too much used to kde's shortcuts. "WikiPedia"

Comment: @Olaf: Indeed "*too much*" .. KDE? "*Kalles Desktop Environment*"?

Comment: @alk "K Desktop Environment"? Don't ask about the "K" :)

Comment: @alk: You are asking what [KDE](https://www.kde.org/) is?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Well, I did. Answer: Don't ask ;-)

Comment: @Olaf: No; but why is "*WP*" is a "*KDE*" shortcut? :-S *lost, sigh*

Comment: @alk: In Plasma: `Alt-F2` (Command-line pops up), type e.g. `wp:byte` (enter); it's actually lowercase. Will open WP with the given searchphrase. Same for e.g. `gg:byte` or `leo:nette sache`. One of the things I miss most if I have to work on Windows. It's actually called "Webshortcuts"/"Web-Kürzel".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator yields the size of a type in *bytes*, where a byte is defined to be the size of a `char`. So `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition, regardless of how many *bits*  `char` has on a given platform.

This applies to both C and C++.

---

From the C11 standard, **6.5.3.4**

> 2. The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand....

Then,

> 4. When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

From the C++11 standard, **5.3.3**

> 1. The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized *type-id*.... ... **`sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are 1.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Re. the down-vote, if there is any inaccuracy in this answer, I'd gladly fix it given some feedback.

Comment: Perhaps some disliked the word "*byte*" and would have liked to read "*... yields the size of a type in `char`s*"?

Comment: @alk Probably someone unfamiliar with the C and C++ standards :-)

Comment: I think you should mention that term `byte` is used as defined in C/C++. Because this term used in many programming languages and not only there. (not related to downvote)

Comment: @Slava I think that is clear enough in the answer, especially given the quotes.

Comment: @juanchopanza I do not think so. Problem is term `byte` is so widely used novadays. Many programming languages, hard drive size etc etc. It is very easy to confuse what you mean by that term.

Comment: @Slava I have already said what a byte means here. It is the size of a `char`. That should be quite simple to understand.

Comment: No it is not simple to understand. If you say that hard drive is 2Terra__bytes__ on platform where char is represented by 32bits, does it mean that each byte on that hard drive is 32bits?

Comment: @Slava Not so simple to understand if one doesn't know how to read and think a little.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know how to read, I just try to explain you that for somebody your answer can be misleading, because term `byte` is used so widely. Look into Superlokkus's answer, he says that this understanding of byte is general, which is is questionable at least. So confusion is definitely there.

Comment: Not only mention that you got downvote most probably because somebody did not like your definition of `byte`

Comment: @Slava I wasn't suggesting you can't read! I know you know all this stuff. I expect readers here to be able to think a little, and I think I have given enough definitions here for someone who is willing to think to figure out that there are different definitions of byte. I have given the one that matters for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Per 5.3.3 [expr.sizeof]

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized type-id. The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type, to an enumeration
>   type whose underlying type is not fixed before all its enumerators have been declared, to the parenthesized name of such types, or to a glvalue that designates a bit-field. ***sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1.***[...]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So no matter how many bits a `char` takes up its size is always 1

Comment: @juanchopanza bytes/bits does it actually matter in the context?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, because "how many bytes a char takes" can only be one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Certainly it matters. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You're just confused with the **difference** between **bytes** and **octets**.

A byte is the size of one character. This yields to the always true `sizeof(char) == 1`, because `sizeof` return the size in **bytes**

While an **octet** consists out of **8 bits**.

On almost all modern platforms, the size of a byte is coincidentally the same as of an octet. That's the reason why it's a common error to mix them up, even book authors and professors are doing this.

Comment: I am afraid you make it even more confusing. Term `byte` used not only in C or C++, there it means the same as `octet`.

Comment: @Slava could you please proof your statement that the size is a byte is fixed in the C/C++ standards?

Comment: By there I mean somewhere else, not C/C++. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: No, byte != octet they have a different definition and knowing the difference is sometimes important. But I thought the 3rd comment to his question (and answer to mine) was from him, and so I bet on the wrong horse.

Comment: byte != octet in C/C++. byte equal to 8 bits in java, c#. byte equal to 8 bits when you say hard drive is 2Terra`byte`s  size. I do not think that C/C++ has monopoly of using this term.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(x)` is returning the size of  `x` expressed in units of size of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no machines where sizeof(char) is 4. It's always 1 byte. That byte might contain 32 bits, but as far as the C compiler is concerned, it's one byte.

The correct name for "8 bits" is octet. The C Standard uses the word "byte" for an object that is the size of a char. Others may use the word "byte" in different ways, often when they mean "octet", but in C (and C++, or Objective-C) it means "object the size of a char". A char may be more than 8 bits, or more than one octet, but it's always one byte.

Answer (score -1):

The question should have been -- Suppose in a hypothetical machine, the `word size(size of registers)` is 32 bits. What would sizeof(char) return?

And answer will be `1 byte`.

> In computing, word is a term for the natural unit of data used by a
>   particular processor design. A word is a fixed-sized piece of data
>   handled as a unit by the instruction set or the hardware of the
>   processor. The number of bits in a word (the word size, word width, or
>   word length) is an important characteristic of any specific processor
>   design or computer architecture. -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29

In you case `word-size` will be 32 bits. Also

> Historically, the byte was the number of bits used to encode a single
>   character of text in a computer and for this reason it is the smallest
>   addressable unit of memory in many computer architectures. -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

1 byte is smallest addressable unit of memory, it cat be 8 bit , 9 bits or 16 bits anything that hardware spec chooses.

As far as `sizeof` is concerned it first determines the type of argument, eventually computes the size in bytes. So, following two C++ statements will produce same result.

```
  int n;
  std::cout<<sizeof(int);
  std::cout<<sizeof(n);
```

Comment: The question as given is perfectly valid. It assumes a `char` is 32 bits. It has nothing to do with the size of a word or of a register.

Comment: spec says nothing about size of char in terms of bits, it says size of char is one byte.. so `char is 32 bits` is an incomplete statement

Comment: The standard also says that a `char` is `CHAR_BIT` bits,  where `CHAR_BIT >= 8`. And a "word" can be multiple bytes, so your suggestion that the question *should* have specified the word size doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @GautamJha It is not, according to C 1 byte is the size of char and not vice verse. Therefore irrespective of how much size is used by a char (which could be 32 bits), it will always return 1

Comment: It is other way round `according to C size of char is one byte, and definition of byte is beyond C's scope`

Comment: No, the definition of "byte" is not "beyond C's scope". The latest draft of the ISO C standard is [N1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). The definition of "byte" is section 3.6: "addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment". The C++ standard has a similar definition. The word "byte" may be used differently in other contexts, but that's how it's used by the C and C++ standards.

Comment: And again, I'm concerned about your first paragraph (it's why I downvoted). The original question asks about an implementation where a `char` is 32 bits. You suggest that the question *should* be about an implementation where a word is 32 bits. The result of `sizeof (char)` is the same in both cases, but this has nothing to do with the size of a "word".